# Creating an OrmLite repository base class for ASP.NET

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to create a general base class that I can use in my whole project. I've written some code but still getting a NULL instance on my DbConnectionFactory.

I've create a ASP.Net web api project and added the AppHost file. I'm using Funq together with Simple Injector to Injector my custom services into the Api Controllers.

**AppHost.cs**

```cs
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Erp", typeof(AppHostService).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {           
        // init
        var simpleInjectorContainer = new SimpleInjector.Container();
        var erpConnection = ConnectionStrings.ErpLocal;           
        var isLocal = HelperTools.IsLocalPath();

        // check
        if (isLocal)
        {
            erpConnection = ConnectionStrings.ErpOnline;               
        }

        // mvc
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));

        // register funq services
        container.Register<IErpDbConnectionFactory>(c => new ErpDbConnectionFactory(erpConnectionString));      
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<CategoryService, ICategoryService>();
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<ManufacturerService, IManufacturerService >();
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<ProductService, IProductService>();
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<ProductAttributeService, IProductAttributeService>();
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<SpecificationAttributeService, ISpecificationAttributeService>();
        //...

        // simple injector services
        SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize(simpleInjectorContainer, isLocal);

        // register SimpleInjector IoC container, so ServiceStack can use it
        container.Adapter = new SimpleInjectorIocAdapter(simpleInjectorContainer);

    }
}
```

**Base Class I'm trying to use**

```cs
public abstract class ApiOrmLiteController : ApiController
{
    IDbConnection _erpDb;       

    public virtual IErpDbConnectionFactory ErpDbConnectionFactory { get; set; }       

    public virtual IDbConnection ErpDb => _erpDb ?? (_erpDb = ErpDbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection());      

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _erpDb?.Dispose();            
    }
}
```

**Web Api Controller**

```cs
public class ShippingController : ApiOrmLiteController
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
    private readonly IAddressService _addressService;
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;
    private readonly IPdfService _pdfService;
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
    private readonly ITranslationService _translationService;       

    #endregion Fields

    #region Ctor

    public ShippingController(IOrderService orderService, IAddressService addressService, ICustomerService customerService, IPdfService pdfService, IMessageService messageService, ITranslationService translationService)
    {

        _orderService = orderService;
        _addressService = addressService;
        _customerService = customerService;
        _pdfService = pdfService;
        _messageService = messageService;
        _translationService = translationService;            
    }

    #endregion Ctor

    [HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("Test")]
    public void Test()
    {
        var products = ErpDb.Select<Category>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use constructor injection for Web API or MVC controllers, alternatively you can access dependencies in ServiceStack's IOC via `HostContext.TryResolve<T>`, e.g:

```
public virtual IDbConnection ErpDb => _erpDb ?? 
    (_erpDb = HostContext.TryResolve<IErpDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection());
```

Comment: Thx @mythz. I will give this a try. Would there be way to use the ServiceStack IOC method for the controllers and Hangfire extension instead of using Simple Injector?

Comment: @Nesse I've never used Hangfire or Simple Injector so couldn't tell you, personally I'd be registering my deps in ServiceStack's IOC and using `HostContex.TryResolve<T>` for accessing deps outside of ServiceStack, the alternative is to use a separate/different IOC for dependencies you want to use outside of ServiceStack. If this was .NET Core you can just register the deps in ASP.NET Core's IOC which is available to ServiceStack and external ASP.NET Core features like MVC/WebApi.